# PHP/MySQL Synchronous innoDB queries works as asynchronous

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I need to update and read data from one table at the same time with different PHP scripts.
I create `$sess` as script session identifier (works around 20 scripts at same time) and I set in the table row the session identifier for 100 rows. After, it will SELECT rows reserved for this script by session identifier. In the while loop the script will do some work with the data and update reserved rows.

But the scripts don't work at same time, the first script works fine, but others not do first query while the first script is running. I see it in my database management app.

```php
$sess = intval(str_replace(".", "", microtime(TRUE)));
sql_query("UPDATE locations SET sess='$sess' WHERE sess='0' LIMIT 100");
$r = sql_query("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE sess='$sess'");
while ($q = sql_row($r))
{
```

Create table syntax

```
CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `area_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeZone` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `lon` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `locationKey` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `cityId` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sess` bigint(100) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `lat` (`lat`),
  KEY `lon` (`lon`),
  KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
  KEY `cityId` (`cityId`),
  KEY `area_id` (`area_id`),
  KEY `sess` (`sess`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3369269 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean? It may help to include the reason why you are updating with the sess flag, then selecting those rows and doing something with them.

Comment: Hi! i have location_id(i need it to get data from server via http) in table locations and rows with data i get data from server and put it in this table and some data i put in other tables. All it i do in "while" loop. 
Session i need to reserve 100 rows for each script.

Comment: But i just want to know thats normal work for innoDB or something wrong?
I used to think that innoDB lock table on row level and i can update and insert other rows if compare with MyIsam tables. I missing something?

Comment: You're looking for the culprit at the wrong place. Can you tell us **how** you ran these two different scripts? Did you open 2 tabs in your browser at once and then one script worked, while the other hangs?

Comment: i do it via started http get request. Yes i do it with browser in two(or more) different tabs.

Comment: Have you tried doing the same but from two different machines? The issue here is how browser "talks" to the web server - more specifically, the optimization steps behind it to make connections more efficient. This is the reason why your second request never reaches the server before the first one is done, hence you interpret that as hanging. In reality, the system you developed actually does work as you intended. What screwed you over is the TCP handling between your browser and web server.

Comment: Although the browser "seems like" it is doing multi-threading, is it really?  Some experiments I have done say that it does not really start one tab's request until another tab's request has finished!  (Perhaps I am saying the same thing @N.B. is saying?)

Comment: @RickJames - I *think* we're talking about the same thing, it's called HTTP pipelining and the culprit is how OS deals with TCP. It wants to pipeline multiple HTTP requests within a single TCP connection. Thus, the first request technically blocks the next one (next one isn't even sent until first receives the reply). The browser is doing multithreading, but web server and OS are trying to be efficient and in this case where requests aren't quick, they're actually making things worse.

Comment: @N.B. - Hmmm.. I'll munch on that.  Thanks for the details.  If it is in the OS, that means that even using two different _brands_ of browser won't get around the serialization.

Comment: So, somehow involving AJAX (instead of waiting for the PHP page to finish) could achieve multi-threading?

Comment: From my experience, I had this happen only with Apache. With `nginx` I wasn't able to experience it and using `nginx` + `http2` definitely **doesn't** produce this result. For HTTP pipelining to work, both browser and server must support it. My memory is fading at this point, but I do remember looking for a way to disable it for use with Apache. At this point, I can't tell whether two different browsers would circumvent the issue - maybe, I guess, we could test? But the culprit has been found, so I take it the OP can look for proper solutions now, MySQL and PHP aren't at fault for this.

Comment: I try run some script from different machines. All works fine. But i confused. How i can run this from one machine.
I develop update data system with huge data. Many agent machines who send data to server via websocket (Ratchet) i think it can be trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Are you inside a transaction (`BEGIN`...`COMMIT`)?  If so, you have locked those 100 rows.  Ditto for `autocommit=0`.

Instead, be sure the `UPDATE` (which is used to assign 100 items from your 'queue' to your process) is in a transaction by itself.

Then, assuming the other threads cannot call `microtime` in the same microsecond (a dubious assumption), the 100 items are safely assigned to you.  Then you can start another transaction (if needed) and process them.

However, that 100-row `SELECT` will unnecessarily put a read lock on those rows.

So...

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE ... LIMIT 100;
SELECT ...
COMMIT;

foreach ...
    START TRANSACTION;
    work on one item
    COMMIT;
end-for
```

It is unclear whether the second START-COMMIT should be inside the `for` loop or outside.  Inside will be slower, but may be 'correct', depending on what "work" you are doing and how long it could take.  (You don't want to `ROLLBACK` 99 successful 'works' because the 100th took too long.)

Are you later doing `DELETE ... WHERE sess = $sess`?  If you are mass-deleting like that, then do it in a separate transaction after the `for` loop.

Goal: segregate the queuing transactions from the application transactions.

Note that the segregation will make it easier to code for errors/deadlocks/etc.  (You *are* checking, correct?)

Comment: I forgot to mention one of my mantras: "Don't queue it, just do it".  (MySQL does not make a good queuing tool.)

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156077/mysql-innodb-row-level-lock-not-works-innodb-lock-full-table-same-as-myisam-engi?noredirect=1#comment56122903_34156077 ?